# Do System Restore points affect the files stored in AppData?

Tags: windows, windows-10, restore, system-restore

I am attempting to recover old System Restore points on a Windows 10 install. I am looking specifically for files that may have been stored in the AppData directory and I need to know whether or not System Restore affects these files

Answer (score 1):

System Restore may affect files in the AppData directory.
This is determined by the extension-part of the file-name.

See the Microsoft article
[Monitored File Name Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sr/monitored-file-extensions?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Ah. This explains why System Restore didn't restore my Chrome history that consists of a "History" file that has no extension ‍♀️

Comment: Ah, damn, I came here to restore my Chrome History too.   damn it.  why didn't chrome put a valid restorable extension on there filenames.  or why didn't Microsoft add the Chrome stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

System Restore will save exact files for the time of which the restore point is made.
This includes files in the AppData directory.